# Dash + Flask маршрутизация

Tags: python, flask, dash

Имею основное приложение написанное в Dash (одностраничное с визуализацией и группировкой данных),
На данный момент пытаюсь реализовать доступ по токенам, соответсвенно токен будет передавать в запросе,

```
# API routing
@app.server.route('/api/<token>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def check_access(token):
    db = Token()
    check_access = db.get_list_tocken(token)
    if check_access == 'denied':
        return 'access denied'
```

Просьба, подсказать, как можно передать token в основное приложение Dash для дальнейших операций с ними? Возможно ли пробросить в app.callback где уже мог бы обрабатывать его?
Спасибо

Comment: Сори за вопрос, а что такое Dash?

Comment: @AndrewHolovko Dash - библиотека для  python, предназначена для создания web-приложений